# SshNet Read out first Host Message with ShellStream

Tags: vb.net, ssh, ssh.net

I am having trouble to process the output of an SshNet ShellStream. Here is my code:

```
        Dim shellStream As Stream = sshConnection.CreateShellStream("main", 100, 30, 800, 600, 4096)
        Dim result(4096) As Byte
        shellStream.Read(result, 0, 0)

        Dim welcomeMessage As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result)
        log(welcomeMessage)
```

"sshConnection" is my SshClient, which connects successfully. "log" is just my output method which writes my results into a textbox and into the console. While the console is full of questionmarks, the textbox doesn't show anything at all. I've seen different approaches reading out the ShellStream and I've also tried several of them (It has made no difference for me when I used `Dim shellStream as ShellStream` and I have also tried using SreamReader on the Stream object).

So I am wondering now if it may not be caused by my approach, but by the fact, that the ShellStream starts to gather the host replies only after it has been created, which would mean that there is no output so far. If that is the case I would like to know how to capture the very first message the host sends when you normally connect to it via a CUI. I need the message to verify that the ssh connection has been established with a specific type of server.

If my idea is completely wrong please tell me how to read out the ShellStream properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Because the `SshClient.CreateShellStream` has the same effect than connecting via an SSH Client from your computer, you can read the very first message with this stream. Here is some working code:

```
Dim sshConnection As SshClient = New SshClient(New ConnectionInfo(hostname, port, username, New PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password)))
Dim shellStream As ShellStream = sshConnection.CreateShellStream("terminal", 150, 500, 800, 500, 8192)
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(shellStream)
Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(shellStream)
Dim cmd As String = "someCommand"
writer.WriteLine(cmd)
writer.Flush()

Thread.Sleep(500)

Dim line As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To 150

     response += line
     line = reader.ReadLine
     response += vbCrLf

 Next
```